# Select count in mysql using group by and repeat the count in each row

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, select

I have my table called 'bills' something like below

```
Bill         item          totalprice

BILL_1       Fossil Watch  9000
BILL_1       Fastrack      -
BILL_1       Fastrack      -
BILL_2       Woodlands     7000
BILL_2       Woodlands     -
BILL_3       Denim Shirt   9000
BILL_3       Levis Jean    -
```

Now i need the result like the below structure

```
Bill         item          totalprice  bill_count

BILL_1       Fossil Watch  9000         3
BILL_1       Fastrack      -            3
BILL_1       Fastrack      -            3
BILL_2       Woodlands     7000         2
BILL_2       Woodlands     -            2
BILL_3       Denim Shirt   9000         2
BILL_3       Levis Jean    -            2
```

I tried with the below query,

*`SELECT bill,item,totalPrice,COUNT(bill) FROM bills GROUP BY bill;`*

but i didn't get the result as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT b.bill, b.item, b.totalPrice, tmp.cnt
FROM bills b
JOIN
(
   select bill, COUNT(bill) as cnt
   from bills
   group by bill
) tmp on tmp.bill = b.bill
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select bill,item,totalPrice,(SELECT 
COUNT(b1.bill)
FROM
bills AS b1 where b1.bill= b.bill
GROUP BY bill) AS bill_count from bills AS b
```